# Error "indices[0] = 0 not in [0,0)" when training CenterNet MobileNetV2 FPN 512x512 with tensorflow object detection api

Tags: object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

I'm running the tensorflow object detection api according to this guide https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#configuring-a-training-job however with a slightly modified code for making the record files and with the following system:

**System information:**

- OS Platform and Distribution: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- Python version:
- TensorFlow version: 2.4.0
- CUDA/cuDNN version: 11.0/8.0.5
- GPU model and memory: GeForce RTX 3090, 24268 MiB

where I want to use the model CenterNet MobileNetV2 FPN 512x512 for boxes from the TensorFlow2 Detection Model Zoo (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md).

I set up the training job according to the guide where I then run

```
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_centernet_mn_fpn --pipeline_config_path=models/my_centernet_mn_fpn/pipeline.config
```

and when doing this I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 115, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 106, in main
    model_lib_v2.train_loop(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 636, in train_loop
    loss = _dist_train_step(train_input_iter)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 888, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2942, in __call__
    return graph_function._call_flat(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1918, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 555, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  indices[0] = 0 is not in [0, 0)
     [[{{node GatherV2_7}}]]
     [[MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  indices[0] = 0 is not in [0, 0)
     [[{{node GatherV2_7}}]]
     [[MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[ToAbsoluteCoordinates_42/Assert/AssertGuard/branch_executed/_386/_1231]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference__dist_train_step_54439]

Function call stack:
_dist_train_step -> _dist_train_step
```

When googling this error there comes some answers that the error is when creating the TFRecord files and that you need to add `include_masks` when creating them. However, when running the other CenterNet models from the model zoo I don't get this error so it seems strange that this would be the error.

Any ideas if it could be anything else?

Comment: did you find out why? I'm having the same problem :(

Comment: nevermind I found out what was, for me at least, the problem. if you are using the default config that came with the model you need to remove from it everything that had to do with keypoints (unless you are actually making training data with keypoints) and if fine tunning add "fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2"

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for Alexandra.
Delete the keypoint association from the config file.

Original code (Delete the part marked "//delete"):

```
model {
  center_net {
    num_classes: 90
    feature_extractor {
      type: "mobilenet_v2_fpn_sep_conv"
    }
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 512
        max_dimension: 512
        pad_to_max_dimension: true
      }
    }
    use_depthwise: true
    object_detection_task {
      task_loss_weight: 1.0
      offset_loss_weight: 1.0
      scale_loss_weight: 0.1
      localization_loss {
        l1_localization_loss {
        }
      }
    }
    object_center_params {
      object_center_loss_weight: 1.0
      classification_loss {
        penalty_reduced_logistic_focal_loss {
          alpha: 2.0
          beta: 4.0
        }
      }
      min_box_overlap_iou: 0.7
      max_box_predictions: 20
    }
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 512
  data_augmentation_options {        // delete
    random_horizontal_flip {           
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 0
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 2
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 1
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 4
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 3
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 6
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 5
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 8
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 7
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 10
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 9
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 12
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 11
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 14
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 13
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 16
      keypoint_flip_permutation: 15
    }
  }                                     // delete
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_patch_gaussian {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
      max_aspect_ratio: 1.7
      random_coef: 0.25
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_hue {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_contrast {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_saturation {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_brightness {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_absolute_pad_image {
      max_height_padding: 200
      max_width_padding: 200
      pad_color: 0.0
      pad_color: 0.0
      pad_color: 0.0
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    adam_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 5e-3
          total_steps: 300000
          warmup_learning_rate: 1e-4
          warmup_steps: 5000
        }
      }
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  num_steps: 300000
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: ""
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/label_map.txt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/train2017-?????-of-00256.tfrecord"
  }
  filenames_shuffle_buffer_size: 256
  num_keypoints: 17  // delete
}
eval_config {
  num_visualizations: 10
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  min_score_threshold: 0.20000000298023224
  max_num_boxes_to_visualize: 20
  batch_size: 1
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/label_map.txt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/val2017-?????-of-00032.tfrecord"
  }
  num_keypoints: 17    // delete
}
```

The code below is how i worked (modified):

```
model {
  center_net {
    num_classes: 4
    feature_extractor {
      type: "mobilenet_v2_fpn_sep_conv"
    }
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 512
        max_dimension: 512
        pad_to_max_dimension: true
      }
    }
    use_depthwise: true
    object_detection_task {
      task_loss_weight: 1.0
      offset_loss_weight: 1.0
      scale_loss_weight: 0.1
      localization_loss {
        l1_localization_loss {
        }
      }
    }
    object_center_params {
      object_center_loss_weight: 1.0
      classification_loss {
        penalty_reduced_logistic_focal_loss {
          alpha: 2.0
          beta: 4.0
        }
      }
      min_box_overlap_iou: 0.7
      max_box_predictions: 20
    }
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 8
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_patch_gaussian {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
      max_aspect_ratio: 1.7
      random_coef: 0.25
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_hue {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_contrast {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_saturation {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_brightness {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_absolute_pad_image {
      max_height_padding: 200
      max_width_padding: 200
      pad_color: 0.0
      pad_color: 0.0
      pad_color: 0.0
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    adam_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 5e-3
          total_steps: 50000
          warmup_learning_rate: 1e-4
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  num_steps: 6000
  max_number_of_boxes: 4
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "pre-trained-models/centernet_mobilenetv2_fpn_od/checkpoint/ckpt-301"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/train_c.record"
  }
  filenames_shuffle_buffer_size: 256
}
eval_config {
  num_visualizations: 10
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  min_score_threshold: 0.20000000298023224
  max_num_boxes_to_visualize: 20
  batch_size: 1
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/test_c.record"
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm ! Thought would be a bigger problem to solve :)